# Light gray link text in “Share” pop-up is almost illegible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, accessibility, popups

The “Share” button at the bottom of a question or answer produces a pop-up, with the link being selected in a (read-only) input field:

[image]

The link text is almost illegible. Would it be possible to choose other colors (with more contrast) to make this better readable?

The above screenshot is from Math Stack Exchange, but it seems to be the same on all networks.

*Note:* This may be a Mac-only problem. I have tested it with Safari and Firefox on macOS 12.5.1. The color settings (such as “Highlight Color”) are the default settings, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox, Android 12

Comment: Yeah same in Chrome under Windows 10 as well. Pretty sure it was changed as part of a recent colors change, e.g. they also changed accepted answer from green to.... something dark which isn't green anymore. (See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so), the color changes are part of "improving color contrast")

Comment: aah... one more change due to "accessbility" stuff.

Comment: @RandomPerson yeah, I can't understand how those color changes help. But, not accessibility expert, so can only hope they did hire such people and not just randomly guessing "better" colors.

Comment: I see *white* text on blue background (Chrome, Windows 11): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPHmI.png

Comment: Windows, latest Firefox also white text on a dark blue background. If I click the hyperlink I get light grey on pale blue.

Comment: NOREPRO on Firefox on Debian Linux or Firefox on Gentoo Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the result of a change to the styling of inputs with the `readonly` attribute. We've created a fix and it should go live within the next 24 hours*. Thanks you for catching this!

***Update**: It'll be early next week. Sorry for the delay but I wasn't able to get a review in time to safely ship it before the weekend.

**Update 2022/09/13**: The fix has been released network wide.

Comment: Oops, so not related to the changes announced [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so)?

Comment: Nope, this change was not accessibility related.

Comment: @DanCormier Thanks for fixing it! Is this a related bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382037?